# How to use multiple sources of parameterized data

Tags: java, junit, parameterized, data-driven-tests

Using [Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) in Junit.

I would like to use two String[] (userId and account) from a separate class. I know this will work fine for the `TestData.users` String[], but I am unsure how to have it also return `TestData.accounts` String[] and pair the data.

The goal is to **pair off each userId and account** into each test.

For example: test1 uses user1 and acct1 to execute the test, test2 uses user2 and acct2 to execute the test, and so forth.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestUpdateUserAccounts extends Base {

private String userId;
private String account;

public TestUpdateUserAccounts(String userId, String account) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.account = account;
}

@Parameters(name = "{0}")
public static Collection userPlusAccount() {
    return Arrays.asList(TestData.users);
    // NEED HELP HERE - HOW TO PAIR EACH TestData.accounts WITH EACH USER
}

@Test
public void checkUserAccount() {
    //code here that will execute some steps
    assertTrue(user.connectedToAccount(account));
}
```

In the `TestData.java`

```
public static String[] users = { "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5" };
public static String[] accounts = { "acct1", "acct2", "acct3", "acct4", "acct5" };
```

Am I missing something quite obvious? Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@Parameters
 public static Collection userPlusAccount() {
  return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
     { "user1", "acct1" },
     { "user2", "acct2" },
     { "user3", "acct3" },
     { "user4", "acct4" },
     { "user5", "acct5" }
  });
 }
```

or

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection userPlusAccount() {
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<TestData.getSize(); i++) {
        list.add(new Object[]{TestData.users[i], TestData.accounts[i]});
    }
}
```

For more information visit:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm

Comment: Yes, I have used the second concept in many of my test suites, but was hoping to find a solution that would be a bit more elastic (based on the length of the string array(s)). If I reduce the test data from 8 pairs to 3 pairs, I do not want to have to update the test class. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try something like the stated above, it will be better if you create a method on TestData that returns the smallest length (either account or users array length)